# Ext JS add action column class from controller

Tags: extjs6.2

I am adding a class to a specific action column in the view but how can I do the same from the controller on action column handler.

```
renderer: function (value, metadata, record) {
            var val= record.data.status.description;
            if ( val == "Request cancelled") {
                metadata.tdCls = 'unlocked';
            }else{
                metadata.tdCls = 'locked';
            }
        },re
```